# SQL filestream authentication best practices

Tags: sql, filestream

I was able to use SQL Filestream fine locally but when I try to upload the files to a remote SQL server which uses SQL authentication, I get a Access Denied exception. Apparently, SQL Filestream only works with Windows Authentication (Integrated Security=true) and not with SQL Authentication which is what we currently have.

No one really uses Windows Authentication in production environment so I just want to know how to overcome this limitation. What's the best practice?

```
    public static void AddItem(RepositoryFile repository, byte[] data)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities()) // DBContext
        {
            db.RepositoryTable.AddObject(repository);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT Data.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM dbo.RepositoryTable WHERE ID='{0}'", repository.ID), con)) // "Data" is the column name which has the FILESTREAM. Data.PathName() gives me the local path to the file.
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var path = reader.GetString(0);
                    var transactionContext = reader.GetSqlBytes(1).Buffer;
                    var fileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, transactionContext, FileAccess.Write);

                    fileStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length); // I get the error at this line.
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are getting the exception?

Comment: "No one really uses Windows Authentication in production environment" I've had implementations where that's not the case for all of the following (Windows Services, Web applications and Desktop apps)

Comment: @Phil Hunt - I've updated the question with my code snippet. I'm getting the error when I try to write the bytes to the file. The process apparently doesn't have access to the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You indeed must use Integrated Authentication when using FILESTREAM:

[FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

You will need to make sure that the Windows account that the production application runs under has been added as a login in SQL Server and has been granted the same permissions as the SQL Authentication account the application currently uses.

You must also ensure that the account has file system permissions to write to the FILESTREAM container.

Comment: does that mean I can give one windows account access to the sql container and the folders and have users impersonate that user when accessing that file stream

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar 'access denied' message using the SqlFileStream example. This had us stumped for days.

A colleague suggested an alternate approach that worked beautifully.  Instead of using SqlFileStream, write the file bytes directly into the SQL server using an INSERT command with an argument that takes the bytes value.  For our table called 'FileData' with columns 'Id' (a guid) and 'Bytes', I would use something like this:

```
Byte[] bytes = // assign your data here

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileData (Id, Bytes) VALUES (@Id, @Bytes)", conn);

    insertCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Guid.NewGuid());
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bytes", bytes);
    insertCmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

    try {
        insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        insertCmd.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        insertCmd.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Notice that the SqlFileStream class is NOT used.

Comment: So how did you do the read of the data.  I can't see how to read the file without SqlFileStream.

Comment: There are many ways to covert file data into a byte array.  One way is to use the `File` class: `Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);`

Comment: Wouldn't this be an issue with extremely large files?